# Proof that $\sigma (p(A)) = p(\sigma (A))$ for any polynomial and matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**My problem**:

Prove that for any matrix $A$ and for any polynomial $p(x)$ we have that $\sigma (p(A)) = p(\sigma (A))$, where $\sigma$ is the spectrum of a matrix. Prove that $A$ is an invertible matrix if no root of $p(x)$ is an eigenvalue.

**My solution**:

For example, if I have the polynomial $\;$ $p(x) = x^2 + x$ $\;$ and the matrix 
$$
        A= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 1 \\
         \end{pmatrix}
$$

then

$$
        p(A)= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 1 \\
         \end{pmatrix}^{2}+  {\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0  \\
        0 & 1 \\
         \end{pmatrix}}=  {\begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0  \\
        0 & 2 \\
         \end{pmatrix}}
$$
$$
$$

We can see that the spectrum of $p(A)$ contains the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2} = 2$

The spectrum of the matrix $A$ contains eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2} = 1$ and if we substitude it into $p(x)$, then $p(\lambda) = p(1) = 1^2 + 1 = 2$

The spectrum of $A$ is the set of its eigenvalues and the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, but I am not sure how to prove $\sigma (p(A)) = p(\sigma (A))$ generally. The second proof I think I understand. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to work in an algebraically closed field, otherwise you might not be able to deal with cases like $p=x^2,\, A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Yes, I need to allow the complex eigenvalues. But what's next please?

Comment: @Leif do you know that every matrix can be upper triangularized? Or, do you know about Jordan form?

Comment: Actually not about that Jordan form, next semester. But I think I have found the solution.